# Laravel Validator : Error messages are not being shown after route redirection

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I am trying to redirect user to the **login** view if he fails to pass the Validator.
Here is code from the login controller that does that :

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

And script indeed does the redirection but the problem is happening with the **$errors** variable part.
By watching how other people are doing that and by reading Laravel Validator documentation the code on my **login** view looks like this :

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Those lines of code comes right after **input submit** button and it is located inside a form .
I have read on some site that it needs to be in that way . Tried also to put it outside a form and nothing happens .

Anyone got the answer ?

Thanks.

On view I tried to also print out the error messages array using the print_r($errors->all()) and the display that I got after form submission and redirection is **"Array ()"** - empty array , no error messages .

Comment: It should work. Are you sure $validator->fails() ?